# Clickhouse - Cumulative Sum or Running Total and Percent to Total

Tags: sql, clickhouse

We have been very encouraged by Clickhouse. However, as we are trying to port all of our existing scripts to Clickhouse, we are running into few roadblocks. **For example:**  `CUMULATIVE SUM or RUNNING TOTAL`. We are trying to find an equivalent of Window Functions e.g. `SUM(SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY SALES)`

Is there a way to get Cumulative Sum or Running Total. Any inputs or guidance is much appreciated. Thanks!

---

This is my second question on Clickhouse (again a fantastic database). We have to port our script which calculates `"Percent to total"`.

For e.g

```
Product | Sales

P1  100 

P2  200

P3  150

P4  50
```

We are looking at writing a script which can populate

```
Product, Sales, PercenttoTotal

P1, 100, 20%

P2, 200, 40%

P3, 150, 30%

P4, 50,  10%
```

Is there a quick way via various functions in Clickhouse using which we can accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to share code or research you've already tried?

Comment: We have tried looking at various options - the obvious one being (in absence of WINDOW functions) to look at JOINS - but this running total would require SELF INNER JOIN with (e.g. a1.Sales <= a2.sales), which Clickhouse doesn't seem to support. Any other thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like that: Select Sales/Sum(Sales)*100 where ... ?

Answer (score 6):

**Percent to total**:

```
SELECT 
   productid,
   count() as per_product_count,
   per_product_count * 100 / ( SELECT count() from prod_sales ) as percent_to_total
FROM prod_sales
GROUP BY productid
```

**Cumulative Sum or Running Total**:

Latest release (v1.1.54310-stable) add support for a function runningIncome (not documented yet) which should work just as runningDifference , but should calculate sum instead of difference.

Check also my answers to this questions on github:

- https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/1470
- https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/1469

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` + `OVER`. For example:

```
SUM(events_count) OVER (ORDER BY interval)
```

It helps me. Found solution here: https://www.interviewquery.com/p/sql-cumulative-sum-guide